# Group array of dates as one string by month

Tags: ios, swift, string, nsdateformatter

I faced with the next challenge. I have an array of dates, for instance: 28.09.21, 30.09.21, 03.10.21, 04.10.21, 05.10.21, 13.10.21. And I want to group all this dates into one string with the following format: [Sep: 28, 30; Oct: 3-5, 13]. As you may see all dates are grouped by month and if the date comes in order it should be grouped into "smaller" group divided by "-". Appraciate for any ideas!

Comment: You should make some attempt and add that code to your question, explaining, specifically, the problem you are having.  To get your started If your array isn't actually `Date` instances, I would parse them so you have an array of `Date`.  Then sort that array in ascending order. Then iterate over the array looking for contiguous dates.  You need to compare the month and the day; If the month is different or the day isn't consecutive you have a discontinuity and you should add the range to the output

Answer (score 1):

Roughly:

1. Create a date formatter and use it to convert your date strings to Date objects.
2. Sort the date objects into numeric order.
3. Map your date objects to DateComponents containing month and day.
4. Break up your array into sub-arrays with the same month.
5. For each month, loop through the entries for that month, buidling a string describing the dates in that month.
6. Combine your strings for each month.